# AJAX Post request is timed out with 502 - Azure Website

Tags: asp.net, ajax, azure

I have an application in ASP.MVC, I haven't encountered any issue working on local, but started to experience "timeouts" with the application deployed on an Azure Website.

Some context; I am uploading files, on upload, there are some logic behind that take some times. In this example, I am uploading 4 files. The Action return after 2.7 minutes for the first file, the 4th one then reach the Action, but the 2 other requests timeout at 4 minutes:
[image: Network]

I have tried:

- $.ajaxSetup() with timeout parameter
- web.config executionTimeout parameter

I would appreciate any tips, I haven't found anything helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I am using a javascript library for the files upload which would initiate the ajax requests on Filemanagement/SaveBlob as soon as the files have been selected.

Answer (score 2):

I have found out that there is a layer between the user and the Website, ARR.
ARR is doing the routing, and it acts as a proxy (hence the 502 Bad Gateway returned by the ARR)

The timeout set on the ARR is not configurable for Websites. It used to be 1 minute, and now is 4 minutes.

I resolved my case by installing the application on a Virtual Machine instead

Comment: I know this question is old. .. But. .. I have similar issue now using PHP with upload form that does actions with XML. .. Is there solution now to finish job even after 4 min passes? (and without moving to Virtual Machine)